# debugging magento line by line for understanding magento

Tags: debug

I am new to magento. How could i debug line by line like other programming languages dot net. 
I have tried with setting developer mode to true. but its shows only error.
I want to see line by line execution for better understanding magento and to see involved tables.

SetEnv MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE “true”

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use netbeans ide with xdebug enable.
http://wiki.netbeans.org/HowToConfigureXDebug

Comment: i am using phpstorm for magicento

Comment: may be this will be helpful.http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/configuring-xdebug.html

Comment: so xdebug enables us to debug line by line if we config

Comment: yes.normally you can use var_dump($var) .also you can use $obj->debug().I think its enough to understand what data contain particular object in magneto.

Comment: k i will try configure xdebug in phpstorm. What $obj->debug() does. and var_dump() not working for functions.